# How to take last three month from given month in php

Tags: php

I Want to take last three month from given month in php 
 for example

```
$mon = 'june';
I want to get March, April, May
```

Is there any way to get this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, there is a way to get this

Comment: Can you please edit on this code.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, don't really understand this vote.

Comment: Acually my output was "june" I want to take three month before "june" that was (March, April, May) Like that i want my result. I can pass any month instead of "june". I have searched lot i am getting three months from current date but i dont wasnt to get from current date.